# How to get robot Trajectory from move_base

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am new to ROS, and I am currently working on an android app to guide people in an indoor environment. I am using a picture of the environment and I would like to show on it the robot trajectory as shown on rviz. Is it possible?
I tried to use a subscriber to the topic /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan but it seems like the same set of Path messages (x, y, z...) is published periodically whatever the goal is (I noticed that using rostopic echo), while on rviz the trajectory changes. Am I doing it wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help

Edit : Here is what I get on rviz (global plan in pink) :

[image: image description]

And what my app draws basing on the x and y from position published on global_plan (the blue line)

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259764/how-to-get-robot-trajectory-from-move_base/) by [Atika](https://answers.ros.org/users/30101/atika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are three topics that are particularly involved in carrying paths that the robot will follow:

- `plan`, published by the global planner (`NavfnROS` is the default). This is the plan all the way to the goal (or to the edge of a map window, if that parameter is set). It is built based on the costmap, but because the costmap only includes sensor data where sensors are present (most often, this is sensors on the robot) it won't plan around obstacles that are not in the static map and are outside the robot's sensor visibility.
- `global_plan` caries the portion of the global plan that the local planner is currently attempting to follow. It is published by the local planner, `TrajectoryPlannerROS`.
- `local_plan` carries the path produced by the local planner, `TrajectoryPlannerROS`. This is also based on the costmap, but because it is only up to a short distance away it will include navigating around any visible obstacles as well. It also takes into account movement of the robot away from the global plan. This is why it often deviates from exactly matching the global path. Keep in mind that depending on how far ahead the local planner is working, there may not be much to show in the visualisation.

To see where the robot intends to go all the way to the goal, you should look at `plan`. To see where it plans to go in the short-term future, look at `global_plan`. To see where it will go immediately, including manoeuvering around obstacles, look at `local_plan`.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atika](https://answers.ros.org/users/30101/atika/) on 2017-04-21**:
Thank you for your answer.
The problem is that when, for example rviz shows a path avoiding obstacles, the path that is drawn on my app subscribed to global_plan is always staight and the robot when it moves on simulation goes straight too. Does rviz or slam alter the trajectory? Or does move_base a

**Comment by [Atika](https://answers.ros.org/users/30101/atika/) on 2017-04-21**:
Or does move_base and global_plan do all the work? If so, how does rviz show a different path than the global_plan one?*

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-23**:
OK, sorry, I misunderstood an aspect of your problem. If you want the exact path the robot will travel, not just a path to the goal, then you also need to consider the `local_plan` topic. This includes avoidance of dynamic obstacles for a short part of the path to the goal. I will update the answer.

**Comment by [Atika](https://answers.ros.org/users/30101/atika/) on 2017-04-30**:
No no, you did understand my problem. I do want to show the global plan to the goal. But using the position parameters published on the global_plan x and y, I get a wrong path on my app. Do the orientation count when drawing a path?
I updated my question with the results I got.